# Discretisation of action-space into tree

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, mesh, reinforcement-learning

How can I dicretize given feasibility region of linear program into tree?

I have region of possible cumulative states of volume, and i want to transform it into tree or graph for future computations.
What algos should I consider to do it?

I am trying to reimplement some optimal control methods from pricing swing contract from folowing paper:
http://paduaresearch.cab.unipd.it/5360/1/Enrico_Edoli_tesi.pdf

[image]

Comment: [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask theoretical questions related to reinforcement learning. I am not fully sure this is a theoretical RL question though. Anyway, if you ask it there, please, delete it from here (to avoid cross-posting, which is generally discouraged).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I am sure that is not theoretical RL question but rather some practical. I think here is the better place.